# Using iText 7 and Java generating pdf can not wrap long English words

Tags: java, itext, itext7

Using iText 7 and Java generating PDF can not wrap long Engish words.

[image: screenshot of pdf]

When there is a long word in a cell, the word is not wrapping inside the cell, rather it is growing and table content is missing in PDF. No idea how to wrap the long word in cell.

I am using iText 7 for PDF generation.

This is my Java file:

```java
package com.sid.pdf;

import java.io.File;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.layout.Document;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Cell;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Table;
import com.itextpdf.layout.property.Property;
import com.itextpdf.layout.splitting.DefaultSplitCharacters;

public class TestTable {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception

    {
        public static final String DEST = "C:\\test.pdf";
        File file = new File(DEST);
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        new TestTable().manipulatePdf(DEST);
        System.out.println("PDF generated....");
    }

    protected void manipulatePdf(String dest) throws Exception {
        PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(dest));
        Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc);
        Table table = new Table(3);
        float tableWidth = doc.getPdfDocument().getDefaultPageSize().getWidth()
                - (doc.getLeftMargin() + doc.getRightMargin());
        table.setWidth(tableWidth);

        Cell cell1 = new Cell();
        Paragraph p = new Paragraph("1");
        p.setProperty(Property.SPLIT_CHARACTERS, new DefaultSplitCharacters());
        cell1.add(p);
        table.addCell(cell1);

        Cell cell2 = new Cell();
        Paragraph p2 = new Paragraph("CamLane_Disp_Warn_Rq_Pr2_e0h2tjvjx5d9y5cbvxqsnhwa7");
        p2.setProperty(Property.SPLIT_CHARACTERS, new DefaultSplitCharacters());
        cell2.add(p2);
        table.addCell(cell2);

        Cell cell3 = new Cell();
        Paragraph p3 = new Paragraph("CamLane_Disp_Warn_Rq_AR2");
        p3.setProperty(Property.SPLIT_CHARACTERS, new DefaultSplitCharacters());
        cell3.add(p3);
        table.addCell(cell3);

        Cell cell4 = new Cell();
        Paragraph p4 = new Paragraph("SQC/CRC");
        p4.setProperty(Property.SPLIT_CHARACTERS, new DefaultSplitCharacters());
        cell4.add(p4);
        table.addCell(cell4);

        Cell cell5 = new Cell();
        Paragraph p5 = new Paragraph("SPV_EngRq1_VAN_Pr2_vx0c4n6d46wgrav5gmco6bvc");
        p5.setProperty(Property.SPLIT_CHARACTERS, new DefaultSplitCharacters());
        cell5.add(p5);
        table.addCell(cell5);

        Cell cell6 = new Cell();
        Paragraph p6 = new Paragraph("Bckl_Sw_Ft_Stat_Pr2_b14xqvpzjykdbhltdyma53upe");
        p6.setProperty(Property.SPLIT_CHARACTERS, new DefaultSplitCharacters());
        cell6.add(p6);
        table.addCell(cell6);
        doc.add(table);
        doc.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Those aren't long English words, are they?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Default split strategy is to find space characters and other characters that the text is usually split at (e.g. hyphen `-`). In your case words don't have such characters. You already made a half-step towards customizing the split characters for your text by defining `SPLIT_CHARACTERS` property, but the missing part is making your custom `ISplitCharacters` implementation. Example implementation that also allows underscores (`_`) as split characters:

```
private static class CustomSplitCharacters extends DefaultSplitCharacters {
    @Override
    public boolean isSplitCharacter(GlyphLine text, int glyphPos) {
        if (!text.get(glyphPos).hasValidUnicode()) {
            return false;
        }
        boolean baseResult = super.isSplitCharacter(text, glyphPos);
        boolean myResult = false;
        Glyph glyph = text.get(glyphPos);
        if (glyph.getUnicode() == '_') {
            myResult = true;
        }
        return myResult || baseResult;
    }
}
```

To enable it just set the new instance instead of the default one to the `SPLIT_CHARACTERS` property:

```
p6.setProperty(Property.SPLIT_CHARACTERS, new CustomSplitCharacters());
```

Visual result:

[image: result]

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution. I got the same solution before as well and about to post in answer section.

Comment: @Srikant If you got "the same solution", then there is no need to post it in another answer, you could simply accept Alexey's answer.

Answer (score 2):

I was trying with below code and worked for me. I have created one custom split 
   character class.

```java
public class SpecificSplitCharacters extends DefaultSplitCharacters {
  @Override
  public boolean isSplitCharacter(GlyphLine text, int glyphPos) {
    if (!text.get(glyphPos).hasValidUnicode()) {
        return false;
    }
    Glyph glyph = text.get(glyphPos);
    if (glyph.getUnicode() == '_') {
        return true;
    } else {
        return super.isSplitCharacter(text, glyphPos);
    }
  }
}
```

Finally we can set custom property to document object as follows:

```
doc.setProperty(Property.SPLIT_CHARACTERS, new SpecificSplitCharacters ());
```

(we can set the property to each paragraph as well)

```
p6.setProperty(Property.SPLIT_CHARACTERS, new SpecificSplitCharacters ());
```

Comment: ...or, in version `7.1.17`, you can set this in the method `BlockElement<T>.SetSplitCharacters(ISplitCharacters)` passing one of the predefined SplitCharacter options: `new DefaultSplitCharacters()`, `new BreakAllSplitCharacters()` or `new KeepAllSplitCharacters()`. You can do it on a `Paragraph` for example.

Comment: Version `.Net 7.1.17`. But probably it's similar on `Java` version.

Comment: Yes it is and it's working great, at least on Java 8 and iText 7.2.4. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm build and pdf viewer on winform c#, in cell build function add this code: **SetMaxWidth**

```
    Paragraph p = new Paragraph(val != null ? val : "");
    ...
    ...
    p.SetFontSize(fontsize);
                p.SetMaxWidth(height - 1000);
                res.Add(p);
    ...
    ...
```

get this result

[image]